# Java sound sampler does not finish getting buffer

Tags: java, audio, sample

I have a code in Java that uses microphone to get random bytes.

I am facing a problem when trying to sample a buffer from a microphone using the classes Java provides.
That code has always worked with an old microphone I have got.
But lately I have bought a more modern webcam (AUKEY PC-W1) that includes a microphone, and when I configure Windows 10 to use that input sound device by default, the function to sample sound does not end, making it imposible to get the sound buffer.

This is the code:

```
class CaptureAudioThread extends Thread
{
    protected final static int BYTES_TO_READ = 64000;

    protected AudioFormat _audioFormat = null;
    protected TargetDataLine _targetDataLine = null;
    protected int _bytesRead = 0;
    protected byte[] _buffer = null;

    public CaptureAudioThread( )
    {
        _buffer = new byte[ BYTES_TO_READ ];
    }

    protected AudioFormat getAudioFormat()
    {
        float sampleRate = 22000.0F;
        //8000,11025,16000,22050,44100
        int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
        //8,16
        int channels = 1;
        //1,2
        boolean signed = true;
        //true,false
        boolean bigEndian = true;
        //true,false
        return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed, bigEndian);
    }//end getAudioFormat

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            _audioFormat = getAudioFormat();
            DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, _audioFormat);
            if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(dataLineInfo))
            {
                throw( new RuntimeException( "Not supported audio format") );
            }
            _targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);

            _targetDataLine.open(_audioFormat);
            _targetDataLine.start();

            _bytesRead = _targetDataLine.read(_buffer, 0, _buffer.length);
        }
        catch( Exception th )
        {
            th.printStackTrace();
            _bytesRead = 0;
        }
        finally
        {
            if( _targetDataLine != null )
            {
                _targetDataLine.stop();
                _targetDataLine.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I use the program with the old microphone it works perfectly.
But when I start the previous thread with the new microphone, it never ends its execution.

I have checked if that code works with other Audio formats (like using samplerate = 44100.0F and channels=2), obtaining the same result

Does anybody know if the problem can be avoided in any way?

Comment: I wanna see some debugging OK?? and why are you using underscores prepended?? is that like a fork lift

Comment: Thanks gpasch, if you need me to provide any extra information, please, ask.
I do usually use underscores in non static class attributes, that is why they have them in the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Why should code work with one microphone but not another? It seems to me that as long as the line is open, any mic will continue to stream data.

To make use of a mic's input line, I take the input and ship out float arrays to a concurrent-safe FIFO queue after assembling the bytes to PCM: `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Float[]>`. This way, one can perform operations on the incoming PCM without blocking the input process. Polling from this queue does not affect the ability of the input line to add to the queue.

IDK if this is the most efficient way to handle mic input, or if it fits your situation (you are using it as a random number generator?), but perhaps this is a plan/pattern worth considering.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
What I understand from your answer is that input line continues getting bytes, but I think that execution should not get stuck in:

    _bytesRead = _targetDataLine.read(_buffer, 0, _buffer.length);

How can I get the buffer if that sentence does never return?
There may be something I am not taking into account, I do not know

Comment: The program "hangs" at the read method line? I can see where that might be theoretically a possible outcome, if the read method makes use of a blocking algorithm and only returns data when it has filled the requested buffer. If that is what is going on, the implication is that the line you are trying to read from is not getting data of the form that the read method is requesting. IDK if that is what is really going on or not, or how to deal with that sort of situation. Is it possible that the line is some sort of bundled AV format and the audio has to be extracted?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with that vocab ...
What do you mean with AV format?
I do neither know how the device gets the buffer, neither if it is encoded in any way, but what Java user expects is to get the decoded buffer ...

Could it be a problem of the device is being used for sampling by another application?

Comment: Yes, the program hangs at that point (the read function)

Comment: Normally this read function blocks the execution during the time needed to fill in the buffer, but in that case (the problem I am refering to), it never returns.

Comment: Sorry for the acronym. I was using AV for audio-visual being paired up. Maybe the signal from your device may be some sort of combination of video and audio bundled together, rather than an audio signal? But truly, I am out of my depth here, and am sorry I can't help more. Yes, sometimes it happens that another application captures exclusive control of a line but I really don't know if that is what is happening to you. Are you able to inspect the lines for information (e.g., name, version vendor) as described at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html ?

Comment: Phil, thank you for your help. I was just trying to get that data you mentioned. I started a new execution and surprisingly that read function does not block anymore. I have changed nothing, but it has started to work ... I do not know ... may be the problem was that that line was blocked by another application that was using it, and now it has stopped using it. Anyway, the problem seems to have gone out.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. It's good to know the outcome. Best of success with your project!